# How can i add custom category description block?

Tags: magento2.2.2

i want to add another category description section after the product listing on category view page.

Is it possible without coding in Magento 2.2?
If not how can i put it?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to do from the admin. You have to create an XML file to get this working. There are a few different ways to do this, but i will show you the way using a custom theme. Create a file here:

> app/design/frontend/{vendor_namespace}/{theme_name}/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

And use this code here:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.description.bottom" template="Magento_Catalog::category/description.phtml" after="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

This will place the secondary category description at the bottom of the content of the page. This might not be the right place for you, but you can play with the `referenceContainer` you are looking to place this in and get the results you are looking for.

### ---Edit---

#### For all categories

After more information, if you are looking to place the same content at the bottom of all categories you can use a Widget to do this. Create a Block in the admin under `Content -> Blocks` with the info that you want. Then create a new Widget under `Content -> Widgets`. Inside here you have to link this new widget to the theme you are using and give it a name. This can't be changed down the line, so if you have multiple themes you will need to make a widget for each.

Inside here you set the required field and choose the location of where you want the widget to go.

[image]

In the other tab you can select the Block you created earlier. Now this block will show up at the bottom of every category on the site.

#### For just one category

There is a little "hack" that you can use if you just want content on just one category. You can create a xml file that is locked to just one id and place your call to a template (or cms block if you like) there.

> app/design/frontend/{vendor_namespace}/{theme_name}/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view_id_20.xml

With this in place, you can now make any calls you like and it will only show on that category.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <!--calling a template file-->
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="single.category.description.bottom" template="Magento_Catalog::category/cat-specific-description.phtml" after="-"/>
            <!--or calling a cms block in from the admin -->
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="your_block">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">your_block_name_here</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: it must be unique content for every category same as default category description.

Comment: as in you need two different text fields in the admin? You want to have a category description in the normal place and another place for category content at the bottom of the page?

Comment: Yes ...........

Comment: I've updated my answer. If it's still not on track, please update your question with exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: it's ok but how can i put it under product listing on category page? https://snag.gy/6WDTAg.jpg

Comment: having the element in the `content` block and then using the call out to `after="-"` will place it there. if it's not there, you need to look at the page and figure out what the structure is and where you need to target the XML. This tool will help out a lot with that: https://github.com/magespecialist/mage-chrome-toolbar